# remote website actions and interaction

Tags: javascript, php, curl, iframe

exists any option, which allows me to visit any website as a "bot" and do there some actions as clicks on elements, write texts into inputs, submit an form...

I've found some solution with php curl, but it only remotely connects to website and can send HTTP requests, but I can't click on elements and redirection doesn't work also.

I'm looking for somethink like iframe with javascript timed action such as:

PSEUDOCODE:

```
if page is loaded {
  find elem with id "button" and click on them
  if redirected page is loaded {
    fint input with id "x" and set value to "y"
    click on submit button
    return innerHTML of element with id "response-text"
  }
}
```

But I cant send data to iframe and find elements in iframe externaly, or I don't know how :(

Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/249623/how-to-simulate-imagebutton-click-via-curl-or-html-form i didnt read deeply into it but it may be helpfull

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it is quite different. He want's to do click on their own website thought curl. It is not problem, if you can edit endpoint website. I want to do click on websites, in which I cannot change source code.

Comment: Check out [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Wazelin it looks, that it can solve my problem :)